# Generating HTML Excel file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am generate dynamic file using StringBuilder. 
I am generating one Table in two row and two column. 
In second row, first column in text and second column in other table.
I try to create this design.
But
Design working on Html page but this design do not work in excel file.

```
strHTML.Append("<table  cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>")
strHTML.Append("<tr><td>text</td>")
strHTML.Append("<td>text</td></tr>")
strHTML.Append("<tr><td>text</td>")``
strHTML.Append("<td><table><td>text</td></table></tr>")
strHTML.Append("</table>")
```

But Working On Excel file this type

```
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>text<table></table></td><td></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strHTML.Append("<td><table><tr><td>text</td></tr></table></td></tr>")
```